# Angular 1.5 angular.js:13236: TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

DEV TOOLS

Angular 1.5

**EDIT: THE SOLUTION**

After almost a day of debugging I found the problem. Good old Angular Batarang. The culprit is the following script which is loaded in the header when you enable the debug tool.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension://aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj/ng-inspector.js"></script></head>
```

Anyone have any idea why I'm getting this exception. I've walked through my code but I'm unable to debug to even find the piece of code that is causing this issue. I've done a step by step debug on HTML as well as JS but unable to narrow it down to a section of code or even js file. Even with one scope i.e. id scope.id:1 I still get it. I've looked at all the other posts with similar type but none of those solutions are working for me.

Exception handler is just as cryptic:

```
Default exception handler. Object {exception: "Exception description : TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined", cause: undefined}
```

Sorry to be this cryptic but I have no idea how to even track / debug this problem.

```
     angular.js:13236: TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined
    at arguments.(anonymous function) (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2001:19)
    at Scope.$digest (http://www.cmo:8888/components/angular/angular.js:16664:23)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2016:23)
    at Scope.$apply (http://www.cmo:8888/components/angular/angular.js:16928:24)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2079:22)
    at done (http://www.cmo:8888/components/angular/angular.js:11266:47)
    at completeRequest (http://www.cmo:8888/components/angular/angular.js:11464:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://www.cmo:8888/components/angular/angular.js:11405:9)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9965Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16682scopePrototype.$digest @ hint.js:2016Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16928scopePrototype.$apply @ hint.js:2079done @ angular.js:11266completeRequest @ angular.js:11464requestLoaded @ angular.js:11405

    angular.js:13236 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
        Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
        at angular.js:68
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16702)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:2016)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:2079)
    at done (angular.js:11266)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11464)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11405)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9965Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16930scopePrototype.$apply @ hint.js:2079done @ angular.js:11266completeRequest @ angular.js:11464requestLoaded @ angular.js:11405
    angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
        Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D(anonymous function) @ angular.js:68Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16702scopePrototype.$digest @ hint.js:2016Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16928scopePrototype.$apply @ hint.js:2079done @ angular.js:11266completeRequest @ angular.js:11464requestLoaded @ angular.js:11405
```

Comment: can u show the code ?

Comment: it is 32 scripts so impossible. Like I said I cannot even narrow it down right now other than if I comment out all init HTML it stops but beyond that nothing.